# Kendo UI JSP DataSourceRequest.java class does NOT work for Spring Data JPA. Which class needs to be used with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: kendo-ui

Kendo UI DataSourceRequest.java class is written for Hibernate. This is used to filter server side data for Grid, Dropdown UI Controls etc. But it does NOT work with Spring JPA. Is there any another class to use with Spring Data JPA  ?
Please guide on this. 
Thanks
S